# iPad web app stored locally

Tags: iphone, ipad, html

I'm writing an iPad Web app witch doesn't really need to be updated over internet.
My problem is that it has to load some kb of data and that makes it a bit slow.
I would really like to improve that and I was wondering if it wasn't possible to save my whole web app on a iOS native app.
I'm not using php, just javascript, css and HTML5.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest checking out HTML5 offline caching:
http://www.html5rocks.com/features/offline

And PhoneGap
http://www.phonegap.com/

Comment: Cool, I'm trying to implement it ;-))
Thanks